# How to set local storage for two separate functions(dark-light mode)

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Newbie coder here. Got the basic function to do as needed but as is I'm clueless to Javascript but willing to learn. I'm borrowing code from all over the web. I'm developing our business website after hours as with my daytime job I'm a construction supervisor so can only do this at night. Now I just need to be able to store the colour theme selection in the localStorage and recall it when the browser re-opens. This is why I'm opting for localStorage.

Have tried the guides on localStorage but I'm dumbstruck as to how to do the calls properly and store the selection. The two buttons functions work perfectly changing the colour of my navbar and changing the most basic colours the body and the font colour.

```
// Light-Mode
function toggleLight() {
    var body = document.getElementById("body");
    var currentClass = body.className;
    body.className = currentClass == "dark-mode" ? "light-mode" : "light-mode";
    document.getElementById("nav").className = "navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark";
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "light-mode")
}

//Dark-Mode        
function toggleDark() {
    var body = document.getElementById("body");
    var currentClass = body.className;
    body.className = currentClass == "light-mode" ? "dark-mode" : "dark-mode";
    document.getElementById("nav").className = "navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light";
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark-mode")
}
```

I expect it to store and recall the last selected colour/theme on browser reload but as it seems I'm missing some major piece of coding. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As just some general advice: **(1)** Your two functions are nearly identical. You may want to consider making them *one* function to avoid duplicated code, and use a parameter for light vs dark. **(2)** You have two ternaries that aren't really serving a purpose. For example, `currentClass == "light-mode" ? "dark-mode" : "dark-mode";` says *"Is the current class `light-mode`? Then set it to `dark-mode`. Otherwise, set it to `dark-mode`."* If the result is the same either way, why check `currentClass` at all? Again, just some pointers. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Link to a pen for the actual template I'm busy with. [link](https://codepen.io/JigsawKilla89/pen/mYymbm)

Comment: Thanx. will have a look at it. Like I said total newbie to coding. Know just the basics of web design. @TylerRoper

Comment: If you look at the developer tools https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/localstorage while on the your pen you see that "theme" is storing just fine. You just need to recall it `local​Storage​.get​Item()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of each function the theme name is saved in localStorage. On `onLoad` event read this value and call respective function:

```
window.onload = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark-mode") {
        toggleDark();
    } else {
        toggleLight(); // consider as default theme
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks this one worked for me. Appreciate the help @Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

You store the theme with `localStorage.setItem()` but never recall it with [`local​Storage​.get​Item()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

on page load:

```
var body = document.getElementById("body");
body.className = local​Storage​.get​Item("theme");
```